# Returning a value of ruby is strange

Tags: ruby, return

could anyone tell me the return value of this function give the parameter listed blew:

```
def sequence(*enumerables)
    enumerables.each do |enumerable|
        print "#{enumerable},"
    end
end

a,b,c = [1,2,3],4..6,'a'..'e'

value = sequence(a,b,c)
print value
```

why the value is evaluated to be:

```
[[1,2,3],4..6,"a".."e"]
```

Comment: what is your expected output? Your code behaves as you wrote it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, why would you expect something different? Also, don't use `enumerables` or `enumerable` as a variable name. You'll regret those when you mistype the case, or do a global search and replace and accidentally change code that shouldn't have been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the last thing left on the stack is the return value of your method. This is *always* the case. If the return value is important, you must pay close attention to how you exit from your method.

The `each` method returns what it has been iterating over. Since the `each` is the last statement in your method, stack-wise, that value gets returned.

You can fix this by returning nothing:

```
def sequence(*enumerables)
  enumerables.each do |enumerable|
    print "#{enumerable},"
  end

  return
end
```

This approach is generally frowned on as the `return` method seems out of place. If the caller of this method is not expecting any particular return value, then it's not necessary.

The alternative is to return something useful:

```
def sequence(*enumerables)
  enumerables.join(",")
end

puts sequence(a,b,c)
```

It's often the case that methods which do not set an expectation for a particular return value may return an arbitrary one.

Answer (score 3):

`enumerables` is an array. The splat (`*`) operator causes this.

The return value of `sequence` is the return value of `enumerables.each` which is `enumerables`

A simple example:

```
def foo(*args)
  args
end

foo(1,2,3,4) == [1,2,3,4] # true
```

Comment: could you tell me why the enumeralbes.each is enumerables? sorry i am new to ruby. thanks

Comment: @bean the return value of `enumerables.each` is `enumerables` - that is to say the return value of `each` is the object it was invoked upon.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning `enumerables`, which is an array containing all the arguments to the method.

What did you expect `value` to contain? You haven't made any explicit attempt to return anything, so whatever value the last statement in the method resolves to "falls off" the method to become its return value.